# How to handle bottom navigation bar's fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed, android-bottomnav

I have four fragments attached in my bottom nav bar. Now I am trying to go from one this fragments to any other fragment by clicking on a cardview. This is working perfectly but when I am going to that fragment to any other fragment(which are attached in nav bar) and pressing back button something weird overlapping is happened.
Here is my nav bar and fragment container activity:
**ShowFragment.java**

```
package com.fahim69.bazaarapp.FragmentHolder;
public class ShowFragment extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView bottomnav;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_fragment);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);
    replacefragment(new HomeFragment());
    bottomnav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    replacefragment(new HomeFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_category:
                    replacefragment(new CategoryFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_cart:
                    replacefragment(new CartFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    replacefragment(new ProfileFragment());
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void replacefragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

And here is my that fragment code from where I am going to different fragment which is not attached to nav bar.

```
package com.fahim69.bazaarapp.Fragment;

public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

CardView fruit, fish, meat, vegetable, cooking, dairy, frozen, snacks, bread, beverage, 
personal_care, hygiene, baby_care, homekitchen, petcare;
ImageView fruit_img, fish_img, meat_img, vegetable_img, cooking_img, dairy_img, frozen_img, 
snacks_img, bread_img, beverage_img, personal_img, hygiene_img, baby_img, home_img, pet_img;
TextView fruit_tv, fish_tv, meat_tv, vegetable_tv, cooking_tv, dairy_tv, frozen_tv, snacks_tv, 
bread_tv, beverage_tv, personal_tv, hygiene_tv, baby_tv, home_tv, pet_tv;


public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
    fruit = view.findViewById(R.id.fruitname);
    fish = view.findViewById(R.id.Fish);
    meat = view.findViewById(R.id.meat);
    vegetable = view.findViewById(R.id.vegetable);
    cooking = view.findViewById(R.id.cooking);
    dairy = view.findViewById(R.id.dairy);
    frozen = view.findViewById(R.id.frozenAndCanned);
    snacks = view.findViewById(R.id.Snacks);
    bread = view.findViewById(R.id.breadandbakery);
    beverage = view.findViewById(R.id.beverages);
    personal_care = view.findViewById(R.id.Personalcare);
    hygiene = view.findViewById(R.id.Hygiene);
    baby_care = view.findViewById(R.id.BabyCare);
    homekitchen = view.findViewById(R.id.HomeandKitchen);
    petcare = view.findViewById(R.id.Petcare);


    fruit_img = view.findViewById(R.id.fruitpic);
    fish_img = view.findViewById(R.id.fish_category_img);
    meat_img = view.findViewById(R.id.meatpic);
    vegetable_img = view.findViewById(R.id.vegetablepic);
    cooking_img = view.findViewById(R.id.cookingpic);
    dairy_img = view.findViewById(R.id.dairypic);
    frozen_img = view.findViewById(R.id.frozenandcannedimg);
    snacks_img = view.findViewById(R.id.snackscatimg);
    bread_img = view.findViewById(R.id.breadandbakeryimg);
    beverage_img = view.findViewById(R.id.beveragesimg);
    personal_img = view.findViewById(R.id.personalcare_img);
    hygiene_img = view.findViewById(R.id.hygiene_img);
    baby_img = view.findViewById(R.id.babycare_img);
    home_img = view.findViewById(R.id.homeandkitchen_img);
    pet_img = view.findViewById(R.id.petcareimg);


    fruit_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name_tv);
    fish_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.fish_category_tv);
    meat_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.meat_cat_tv);
    vegetable_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.vegetable_cat_tv);
    cooking_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.cooking_cat_tv);
    dairy_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.dairy_cat_tv);
    frozen_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.frozen_cat_tv);
    snacks_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.snacks_tv);
    bread_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.breadbackery_tv);
    beverage_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.Beverage_tv);
    personal_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.personal_care_tv);
    hygiene_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.hygiene_tv);
    baby_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.babycare_tv);
    home_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.homeandkitchen_tv);
    pet_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.petcare_tv);
    BottomNavigationView item = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);



    fruit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new FruitCategory();
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

[image: From this fragment I am going to another fragment]

[image: And destination fragment picture]

[image: And now I am going to this fragment from destination fragment using nav bar]

[image: And this overlap is occured after back button is pressed]

I tried a lot of stuff but problem is solving. Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

**It's happening because you don't properly work with your back stack.**

Your current fragment flow:

1. `boot()` -> No fragment attached
2. `onCreate()` -> Add `HomeFragment` (nothing in back stack).
3. `onTabClick()` -> Replacing current fragment with `CategoryFragment` (nothing in back stack)
4. `openFruitDetails()` -> Replace current fragment with `FruitCategory` and adding to back stack current fragment (now `CategoryFragment` in back stack)
5. `onTabClick()` -> Replacing current fragment with `ProfileFragment` (`CategoryFragment` **still** in back stack)
6. `onBackClick()` -> Pop back `CategoryFragment` from back stack.

**What you can do with it?**

1. Bad one -> Don't add to back stack any of your fragments.
2. Good one -> Add navigation library `jetpack navigation`, `cicerone`, `modo` etc.
3. Hard one -> Create your own fragment manager wrapper implementation for resolving such behavior.

Comment: If I don't add to backstack then I will directly exit from the application.

Comment: @c19-10-46-fahim Yep, that's the correct behavior without back stack.

Comment: Ok please help me to achieve this.When I will back press it will return to fruit category and from there if I back press again it will return category fragment. Thanks for everything you told till now.